# How to get right number format in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, contacts, google-contacts-api

I have received an excel sheet with a list of customers details. For some reason, the column that contains their number, is of different variations. E.g. some are country code etc. I want all the numbers to be in the following format 07######### (where the # corresponds to different digits). Some numbers are in the format of just '7000000000' and doesn't include the 0 at the front. Is there anyway to convert the already existing numbers to one format of 07#########

Comment: Do you want it to be a fixed number of digits? (I mean to fill with zeros on the left to reach, say 11 digits)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you want the number to appear with 11 digits, padding zeros on the left to have always 11 digits.

You can achieve this with the `Custom` number formatting in Excel:

Select the Range, Right Click, Format Cells --> Custom, and in the `Type` box type `00000000000` (11 zeros).